# Distributing Windows Application through internet

Tags: deployment

We have window application developed in .Net and want  perfect deployment technology

- which enables easy application installation and upgrading.
- The client can be accessed from anywhere in the world where an Internet connection is available.
- In future we want the same deployment technology for provide support user's who use Window 7 and
  Window 8

  Looking at the the initial requirement we have decided to use Click Once technology 
  but found many issues in the deployment. They are below

  - You will need to sign a Click Once application with trusted certificate
    otherwise it is  blocked and instantly removed by Antivirus program.
  - ClickOnce may not be supported by all browsers , the behavior are different in IE and
    other  browser
  - ClickOnce to doesn't install components into the GAC  , doesn't installed in the program 
    files rather it install and maintain user wise in the client machine.
  - ClickOnce has issue with proxy network and unable to customize the setup screen.
  - Community has faced many issues with ClickOnce Setup  and  does not have enough solution or
    updates on Click Once  technology  solution

Do we have perfect deployment solution for window app over internet other than ClickOnce? Which methodology is widely used  for window app deployment over internet?

Which deployment technology provide better success rate  for easily maintenance and version update for the Window app over internet ?

Comment: `"[We] want perfect deployment technology"` - So does Microsoft, actually.  If you come up with one, I'm sure they'd be interested to know about it.

Comment: Sorry David about my statement here i was just  want to know any solution to the issue mention

Answer (score 0):

You could build it as a standard executable and create an installer. A good way to make an installer is [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). However, the user has to have .Net Framework already installed.

As of Windows Vista, version 2.0 is included, Windows 7 includes 3.5, and Windows 8 includes 4.5. If you change the target .Net Framework of your application you can target these systems. Go to Properties > Target Framework > Choose 2.0, 3.5, or 4.5 (client profile if available).

As for updates, you should implement this in your application on your own or get another third-party updater. I don't know any good ones though.